# FakerPHP generate names in several locales without titles

Tags: php, faker, php-faker

I have a script to generate a list of names using FakerPHP in different Locales:

```php
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php");
$gen_num = $sortBy = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'num2gen', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, array('options' => array('default' => 30, 'min' => 10, 'max' => 300)));

$faker_langs = ['da_DK', 'sv_SE', 'nb_NO', 'fr_FR', 'pl_PL', 'fi_FI', 'en_GB']; //'de_DE', 
$fakers = [];
foreach ($faker_langs as $l) {
    $fakers[] = Faker\Factory::create($l);
}


for ($x = 0; $x < $gen_num; $x++) {
    $lang = rand(0, count($faker_langs) - 1);
    echo $fakers[$lang]->name() . "\n";
}
```

I want this list to validate full names, but the titles that are generated in Polish and German introduce a lot of noise.

I noticed that the Danish formats do not include titles, but the German and Polish do:

### Danish

https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker/blob/main/src/Faker/Provider/da_DK/Person.php

```php
    protected static $maleNameFormats = [
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{middleName}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{middleName}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{middleName}}-{{middleName}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{middleName}} {{middleName}}-{{lastName}}',
    ];
```

### German

https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker/blob/main/src/Faker/Provider/de_DE/Person.php

```php
    protected static $maleNameFormats = [
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}-{{lastName}}',
        '{{titleMale}} {{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}}',
        '{{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}} {{suffix}}',
        '{{titleMale}} {{firstNameMale}} {{lastName}} {{suffix}}',
    ];
```

Is it possible to omit the `{{titleMale}}` and `{{suffix}}` ordo I have to create a new `Provider` inherriting the de_DE one and overriding the `$maleNameFormats` for the languages that have titles in their formatters?

Comment: use ``echo $fakers[$lang]->firstName . ' ' . $fakers[$lang]->lastName . "\n";`` instead?

Comment: @OMiShah That solves part of the issue - I actually want the hyphenated and middle name cases as well...